# Using ggplot to produce bar plot of selected rows of a large csv file

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2

I am trying to use R and ggplot to produce bar charts of word frequency counts from a large spreadsheet, instead of using Excel for this. I have written a function to extract the first row (for time periods) and then required row from the csv file, to make a new dataframe with this in two columns, then to plot this data as a bar chart. However, the plot produced has a y-axis without a linear scale. Can anybody help to tell me why this is and how to fix it? (ideally a more simple solution!)

The function is as follows, where 'term' indicates the row of the csv file ('data') I'm interested in:

```
make_plot <- function(data, term){
  periods = data[1,]
  results = data[data$V1 == term,]
  df = merge(x=results, y=periods, all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
  df = as.data.frame(t(df))
  df = df[-1,]
  plot = ggplot(df, aes(V1, V2)) + geom_col() + labs(x="Period", y="Freq") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
  return(df)
}
```

This gives a dataframe looking like this:

```
> head(df)
            V1   V2
V2 Freq_2014q4 2226
V3 Freq_2015q1 2444
V4 Freq_2015q2 2088
V5 Freq_2015q3 2688
V6 Freq_2015q4 2804
V7 Freq_2016q1 8794
```

And a plot like this:
[image]

Comment: Try adding `df$V2 = as.numeric(df$V2)` before the `plot` line.

Comment: Thanks. That changes the y-axis, but it seems to change the values in V2 to much smaller numbers? If I don't do that, and ask the class of V2 it reports it as 'factor' - any way to change this to numeric and keep the original, correct value?

Comment: I found that its necessary to do `as.numeric(as.character(df$V2))` and that works now. Thanks for your help.